# Accessing Silverlight Control template items codebehind

Tags: c#, silverlight, layout, silverlight-4.0, controltemplates

I have a control template in page Layout as following.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" TargetType="esri:MapTip">
                <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="#DDFFEEEE" BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="#99FF0000">
                    <StackPanel Background="#DDFFFFFF">

                      <sdk:TabControl Height="180" Margin="5"  Name="tabControl1"  Width="300">      
                               <sdk:TabItem Header="Info" Name="infoTab">

                               <TextBlock x:Name="cityInfoTxt" Tag="{Binding [City_ID]}"/>    

                               </sdk:TabItem>
                        </sdk:TabControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

In code behind how can I access the  ??

I tried this,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var te = this.LayoutRoot.Resources["myTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;

}
```

but can not access the textblock in the tab control.

Comment: Templates are just a pattern to follow when creating elements for you, they are not the elements themselves (as they could be multiple instances using the same template). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I Actually update textblock in template

Comment: Do you mean the text property? If so, that should be done via a binding which will pull the value (rather than try and push the value into it).

Comment: Not property. I wanna access <TextBlock x:Name="cityInfoTxt" Tag="{Binding [City_ID]}"/>

Answer (score 0):

override the method OnAplyTemplate() on code behind and try to find your component.

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var myTextBlock = GetTemplateChild("cityInfoTxt") as TextBlock;
    }
```

Hope it helps